# Is there a way to recover the ID/number of the last perforce shelve created?

Tags: perforce

I created a perforce shelve with changes in a couple of files. I created a shelve and got an ID which I gave to my project member for review. But I didn't note it down.
Is there a way to get the ID/number of all the past shelves created ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do:

```
p4 changes --me -s shelved
```

to get all changelists (`p4 changes`) created by you (`--me`) with a status of shelved (`-s shelved`).  (Note that a "shelved" change is simply a `*pending*` change that has shelved files associated with it.)

If you specifically want the last one, add the `-m 1` flag (`m`aximum of `1` result; this flag works on most Perforce commands that list a bunch of things).